# LibreOffice - getting German spell checking to work (Debian)

Tags: debian, libreoffice, spell-check

I'm using Debian Jessie, LibreOffice is 4.3.3.2. I'm having a document for which the text language is 'German (Austria)', alternatively I tried 'German (Germany)'. I can't spell check my text. If I select 'Tools > Spelling and Grammar...' a 'Spelling' dialog pops up with another stupid modal dialog on top that reads

> LibreOffice 4.3.3.2
>   Continue checking at beginning of document?

[image]

followed (no matter what I click) by

> The spellcheck is complete

Although the text obviously contains mistakes. The text language combo box of the underlying inactive dialog is empty, and also there are no wavy lines in the text as I type.

I already tried `apt-get install libreoffice-l10n-de`, and also I went through [this process](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/23385/how-to-get-language-module-for-spell-check-debian-linux/) of manually downloading some `.oxt` package from the website and adding it with the extension manager.

Simply, I don't get any German spell checking whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking again at the last output from `apt-get`, I figured I need to also install these two packages:

- `hunspell-de-de`
- `myspell-de-de`

Then choosing `German (Germany)` for the whole text makes it work. (I guess for Austria I could also install de-at).

In the character format language setting, 'ABC' icons appear now next to the supported languages.

[image]